# Filtering ports based on traffic content

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have the following scenario:

```
$$ = Background application

Hex# = Normal users

@@ = Attackers
```

Currently, if anyone connects to `$$` via port `80` (as example: not a web server), and sends `"VERSION"`, `$$` will return `"Program XX v10.0.0"` (example).

With this, attackers can detect if a particular IP is running a specific software. I can choose to change the port to use a non common port, so that the attackers cannot blindly connect to `port 443` in a IP range sweep to identify the IP that is running `$$`.

I can also block ping to give out the signal that the IP is not alive, but that still doesn't stop the attackers from trying to connect to each individual port to identify the existence of the `$$` running.

My question is, how do I actually block anyone that attempts to send the `"VERSION"` (example) to `$$`?

Comment: Hello SpacemanSpiff,

What about software based instead of hardware based firewalls?

Comment: A proxy server or reverse proxy may get you closer to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

There are several application layer firewalls out there that are capable of detecting the traffic based on the payload/content instead of IP and Port number. The two I am familiar with are SonicWall and PaloAlto networks. You didn't say anything about "Free" so... there are two solutions that more than meet your requirements.